# Give the combinatorial proof of the identity $\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n} \binom{k-1+i}{k-1} = \binom{n+k}{k}$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients, combinatorial-proofs

Given the identity

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n} \binom{k-1+i}{k-1} = \binom{n+k}{k}$$

Need to give a *combinatorial* proof

a) in terms of subsets

b) by interpreting the parts in terms of compositions of integers

I should not use induction or any other ways...

Please help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

HINTS:

1. Consider a $k$-element subset of $[n+k]=\{1,\dots,n+k\}$; it has a maximum element, which can be anything from $k$ through $n+k$. How many such subsets are there with maximum element $k+i$ for $i=0,\dots,n$?
2. There are $\binom{k-1+i}{k-1}$ compositions of $k+i$ with $k$ terms. There are $\binom{n+k}k$ compositions of $n+k+1$ with $k+1$ terms.

Comment: 2)Let's split n+k into two parts: 1 and n+k-1. 
including 1, we have $\binom{n+k-1}{k-1}$, otherwise $\binom{n+k-1}{k}$.
Hence $\binom{n+k}{k}$= $\binom{n+k-1}{k-1}$+$\binom{n+k-1}{k}$

Using $\binom{n+k-1}{k}$,repeat the procedure till $\binom{k-1}{k-1}$.



1)I'm still confused here. I understand that the answer to your question should be the identity, however I don't quite understand how this works.

Comment: (1) Oops: the maximum should have been $k+i$, not $k-1+i$. If $k+i$ is the maximum element of a $k$-element subset of $[n+k]$, the other $k-1$ elements can be any $k-1$ elements of the set $[k-1+i]$, and there are $\binom{k-1+i}{k-1}$ of them. Thus, the summation is just counting the $k$-element subsets of $n+k$ in groups corresponding to their maximum elements. (2) You’re suggesting an informal proof by induction, not a combinatorial argument. You do not want an argument by induction; you want to show that the two sides are counting the same set of compositions in two different ways.

Comment: "There are $\binom{k-1+i}{k-1}$ compositions of $k+i$ with $k$ terms. There are $\binom{n+k}k$ compositions of $n+k+1$ with $k+1$ terms." Is this already an answer? If so could you explain it to me?

Comment: @vercammen: Suppose that you have a composition of $n+k+1$ with $k+1$ terms; when you throw away the last term, what’s left is a composition with $k$ terms of some number between $k$ and $k+n$ inclusive.

Comment: finally clear. thank you!

Comment: @vercammen: You’re welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Use $\binom{k}{r} = \binom{k-1}{r} + \binom {k-1}{r-1}$ repeatedly on the expansion of sum.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\,{#1}\,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Leftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\color{#f00}{\sum_{j = 0}^{n}{k - 1 + j \choose k - 1}} & =
\sum_{j = 0}^{n}{k - 1 + j \choose j} =
\sum_{j = 0}^{n}{-k + 1 - j + j - 1 \choose j}\pars{-1}^{j} =
\sum_{j = 0}^{n}{-k \choose j}\pars{-1}^{j}
\\[3mm] & =
\sum_{j = -\infty}^{n}{-k \choose j}\pars{-1}^{j} =
\sum_{j = -n}^{\infty}{-k \choose -j}\pars{-1}^{-j} =
\sum_{j = 0}^{\infty}{-k \choose n - j}\pars{-1}^{j + n} =
\\[3mm] & =
\pars{-1}^{n}\sum_{j = 0}^{\infty}\pars{-1}^{j}\oint_{\verts{z} = 1^{-}}
{\pars{1 + z}^{-k} \over z^{n - j + 1}}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[3mm] & =
\pars{-1}^{n}\oint_{\verts{z} = 1^{-}}
{\pars{1 + z}^{-k} \over z^{n + 1}}\sum_{j = 0}^{\infty}\pars{-z}^{j}
\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic} =
\pars{-1}^{n}\oint_{\verts{z} = 1^{-}}
{\pars{1 + z}^{-k - 1} \over z^{n + 1}}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[3mm] & =
\pars{-1}^{n}{-k - 1 \choose n} =
\pars{-1}^{n}{k + 1 + n - 1 \choose n}\pars{-1}^{n} =
{n + k \choose n} = \color{#f00}{n + k \choose k}
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, both the LHS and RHS count the number of non-negative integer solutions to the inequality $\displaystyle \sum_{r=0}^{k}x_{r} \leq n$ which can be readily seen via the double counting below:

1) From the LHS, this inequality can be written as $n+1$ equalities of the form $\displaystyle \sum_{r=0}^{k}x_{r} = i$ where $i=0,1, \ldots n$, each of which have $\displaystyle \binom{k+i-1}{k-1}$ solutions in the non-negative integers and hence the total number of solutions is $\displaystyle \sum_{i=0}^{n}\binom{k+i-1}{k-1}$.

2) From the RHS viewpoint, we can convert this inequality into an equality by adding a slack variable $x_{k+1}$ on the LHS to obtain $\displaystyle \sum_{r=0}^{k+1}x_{r} = n$ which of course has $\displaystyle \binom{n+k}{k}$ solutions in the non-negative integers.